# Why some objects in my gridview appear?

Tags: android, gridview, image-processing, bitmap

This is the button I press for the action

```
button7.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent envent) {
        // Pants
        bp = 7;
        pantsi=1;
        button7.setPressed(true);
        setTab(7);
        resetImageBut();
        culori[0] = 0xfffaf3e6;
        if (getS() == 1) {
            culori[1] = 0xffffffff;
            culori[2] = 0xff787878;
            culori[3] = 0xff2D2D2D;
            culori[4] = 0xff164E94;
            culori[5] = 0xff00A1E4;
            culori[6] = 0xff36B33A;
            culori[7] = 0xffFDD50C;
            culori[8] = 0xffE91C1C;
            culori[9] = 0xffA68F5A;
        } else {
            culori[1] = 0xffB87CDB;
            culori[2] = 0xffF97EB1;
            culori[3] = 0xffE91A46;
            culori[4] = 0xffFFE35F;
            culori[5] = 0xff009E8E;
            culori[6] = 0xff2A88D1;
            culori[7] = 0xff3D5782;
            culori[8] = 0xff2D2D2D;
            culori[9] = 0xffffffff;
        }
        imgb2.getBackground().setColorFilter(culori[1], PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        imgb3.getBackground().setColorFilter(culori[2], PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        imgb4.getBackground().setColorFilter(culori[3], PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        imgb5.getBackground().setColorFilter(culori[4], PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        imgb6.getBackground().setColorFilter(culori[5], PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        imgb7.getBackground().setColorFilter(culori[6], PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        imgb8.getBackground().setColorFilter(culori[7], PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        imgb9.getBackground().setColorFilter(culori[8], PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        imgb10.getBackground().setColorFilter(culori[9], PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        // imgb10.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        button3.setPressed(false);
        button4.setPressed(false);
        button5.setPressed(false);
        button6.setPressed(false);
        button8.setPressed(false);
        button9.setPressed(false);
        setColor(culori[0]);
        if(getS()==1){
            cbottomm=culori[0];
        }else if(getS()==2){
            cbottomf=culori[0];
        }
        adapterPants.notifyDataSetChanged();
        gridview.setAdapter(adapterPants);
        mGLView.invalidate();
        gridview.smoothScrollBy(5000, 500);
        return true;
    }
});
```

This notifies my image adapter which is:

```
public class ImageAdapterShoes extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;


public ImageAdapterShoes(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds8.length;

}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageView.setMaxWidth(20);
        imageView.setMaxHeight(100);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
    //    if (!Project.noFilter)
     //     imageView.setColorFilter(Project.getColor(), Mode.MULTIPLY);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    if(Project.getS()==2){  
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds8[position]);
    }else if(Project.getS()==1){
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds8m[position]);
    }

    imageView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();


    if (Project.getS()==1){

        switch(position)
        {
        case 0:
            bmap=SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 60, 205, 140, 225, 195, 240,Project.cshoesm);
            break;
        case 1:
                bmap=SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 60, 70, 60, 70, 60, 70,Project.cshoesm);
            break;
        case 2: 
                bmap=SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 155, 205, 75, 170, 35, 150,Project.cshoesm);
            break;
        case 3:
                bmap=SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 185, 240, 35, 80, 35, 50,Project.cshoesm);
            break;
        case 4:
                bmap=SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 200, 235, 30, 40, 30, 45,Project.cshoesm);
            break;
        case 5:
                bmap=SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 170, 210, 200, 240, 210, 255,Project.cshoesm);
            break;
        case 6:
                bmap=SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 240, 255, 40, 60, 40, 60,Project.cshoesm);
            break;
        case 7:
                bmap=SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 245, 255, 165, 180, 40, 60,Project.cshoesm);
            break;
        case 8:
                bmap=SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 130, 145, 120, 135, 110, 125,Project.cshoesm);
            break;
        case 9:
                bmap=SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 110, 130, 30, 45, 0, 10,Project.cshoesm);
            break;
        case 10:
                bmap=SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 160, 180, 80, 100, 40, 60,Project.cshoesm);
            break;
        case 11:
                bmap=SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 220, 235, 30, 45, 30, 50,Project.cshoesm);
            break;
        case 12:
                bmap=SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 250, 255, 250, 255, 250, 255,Project.cshoesm);
            break;
        case 13:
                bmap=SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 85, 100, 85, 100, 85, 100,Project.cshoesm);
            break;

        }
    if (Project.getS()==2){


        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            bmap = SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 145, 160, 205,
                    220, 140, 155, Project.cshoesf);
            break;
        case 1:
            bmap = SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 60, 70, 60, 70,
                    60, 70, Project.cshoesf);
            break;
        case 2:
            bmap = SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 245, 255, 205,
                    220, 40, 60, Project.cshoesf);
            break;
        case 3:
            bmap = SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 230, 255, 130,
                    210, 170, 230, Project.cshoesf);
            break;
        case 4:
            bmap = SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 215, 230, 210,
                    230, 195, 210, Project.cshoesf);
            break;
        case 5:
            bmap = SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 245, 255, 240,
                    255, 190, 205, Project.cshoesf);
            break;
        case 6:
            bmap = SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 250, 255, 125,
                    140, 40, 55, Project.cshoesf);
            break;
        case 7:
            bmap = SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 135, 150, 125,
                    140, 110, 130, Project.cshoesf);
            break;
        case 8:
            bmap = SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 170, 190, 215,
                    230, 220, 235, Project.cshoesf);
            break;
        case 9:
            bmap = SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 235, 250, 165,
                    180, 190, 205, Project.cshoesf);
            break;
        case 10:
            bmap = SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 235, 250, 145,
                    160, 185, 200, Project.cshoesf);
            break;
        case 11:
            bmap = SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 205, 250, 205,
                    250, 200, 245, Project.cshoesf);
            break;
        case 12:
            bmap = SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 75, 170, 35, 130,
                    20, 90, Project.cshoesf);
            break;
        case 13:
            bmap = SquareShoes.repleceIntervalColor(bmap, 240, 255, 240,
                    255, 240, 255, Project.cshoesf);
        }
    }

       imageView.setImageBitmap(bmap);


    return imageView;
}

// references to our images


    private Integer[] mThumbIds8 = {
            R.drawable.girl_shoes_01,R.drawable.girl_shoes_02,
            R.drawable.girl_shoes_03,R.drawable.girl_shoes_04,
            R.drawable.girl_shoes_05,R.drawable.girl_shoes_06,
            R.drawable.girl_shoes_07,R.drawable.girl_shoes_08,
            R.drawable.girl_shoes_09,R.drawable.girl_shoes_10,
            R.drawable.girl_shoes_11,R.drawable.girl_shoes_12,
            R.drawable.girl_shoes_13,R.drawable.girl_shoes_14,
        };

    private Integer[] mThumbIds8m = {
            R.drawable.boy_shoes_01,R.drawable.boy_shoes_02,
            R.drawable.boy_shoes_03,R.drawable.boy_shoes_04,
            R.drawable.boy_shoes_05,R.drawable.boy_shoes_06,
            R.drawable.boy_shoes_07,R.drawable.boy_shoes_08,
            R.drawable.boy_shoes_09,R.drawable.boy_shoes_10,
            R.drawable.boy_shoes_11,R.drawable.boy_shoes_12,
            R.drawable.boy_shoes_13,R.drawable.boy_shoes_14,
        };
```

}

SquareShoes is the class that I use to create a square in OpenGL to load the textures for my SurfaceView (not in the Gridview)
The repleceIntervalColor function from the SquareShoes is:

```
public static Bitmap repleceIntervalColor(Bitmap bitmap,int redStart,int redEnd,int greenStart, int greenEnd,int blueStart, int blueEnd,int colorNew) {
    if (bitmap != null) {
        int picw = bitmap.getWidth();
        int pich = bitmap.getHeight();
        int[] pix = new int[picw * pich];
        bitmap.getPixels(pix, 0, picw, 0, 0, picw, pich);
        for (int y = 0; y < pich; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < picw; x++) {
                int index = y * picw + x;
                if (Project.shoesi==0)
                if (Color.alpha(pix[index])!=0)
                    if (
                        ((Color.red(pix[index]) >= redStart)&&(Color.red(pix[index]) <= redEnd))&&
                        ((Color.green(pix[index]) >= greenStart)&&(Color.green(pix[index]) <= greenEnd))&&
                        ((Color.blue(pix[index]) >= blueStart)&&(Color.blue(pix[index]) <= blueEnd))
                    ){
                        pix[index] = colorNew;
                    }
                }
            }
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(pix, picw, pich,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        return bm;
    }
    return null;
}
```

As i said, this program loads some objects in the gridview, but some don't appear from the beginning, you have to scroll down and up to make them appear. What could i do?

Comment: Why are you using hex values? You should try and avoid those if possible. They are generally generated by the compiler.

Comment: I'm a beginner to all this android stuff. didn't knew. Could that be the problem? what should i use?

Comment: They are colors, so hex values are fine. But you could export them to a res/values/colors.xml, which would be more tidier. But in your adapter, you should use a switch-statement instead of a bunchfull of if's !

Comment: Changed it like that, still doesn't show all items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used:
Bitmap bmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

Instead of:

imageView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
And it works.